# Условное предложение в русском языке

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли такое предложение: "Если я плохо себя чувствую, то я пойду к врачу"?

Answer (score 4):

Так сказать **нельзя**: здесь получилось английское соотношение времён для условного предложения о будущем, невозможное в русском. Правильный вариант с условием в будущем:

> Если я себя плохо **по**чувствую, то я пойду к врачу.

В исходном же варианте даже *нельзя понять*, какой из трёх разных смыслов пытаются выразить: "если + глагол настоящего времени" соответствует ситуации, *повторявшейся в прошлом*, и не относится к будущему условию; с этим может сочетаться другой глагол настоящего времени, но *не будущего*:

> Если я плохо себя чувствую, я иду к врачу.

Здесь смысл в том, что человек обычно делает в ситуации плохого самочувствия. Если же речь идёт о текущей ситуации с самочувствием и о грядущем походе к врачу, то нужно заменить "если" чем-то другим, чтобы отнести самочувствие к *текущему* моменту:

> **Раз уж** я себя плохо чувствую, то я пойду к врачу.

**P.S.** 
Редкий контекст, когда исходный вариант может быть оправдан - в порядке *самоиронии* ("не знаю пока, насколько плохо я себя чувствую - сейчас буду это определять"):

> Идти ли сегодня на работу - не могу толком оценить своё самочувствие,
>   но сейчас попытаюсь. *Если я плохо себя чувствую, то я пойду к врачу.*

Comment: Совершенно верно, в ЕГЭ есть такое задание: найдите грамматическую ошибку "нарушение видо-временной связи"

Answer (score 1):

**Если я плохо себя чувствую, то я пойду к врачу.**

Думаю, что в этом предложение **неверное соотношение глагольных форм,** их нужно изменить.

Вариант 1. **Если я плохо себя чувствую, то я иду к врачу**.

Такое предложение имеет значение **реализованного повторяющегося** условия. Оно описывает  повторяющуюся ситуацию и близко к придаточному со значением временной обусловленности: **Когда** я плохо себя чувствую, то я иду к врачу.

Вариант 2. **Если я плохо себя почувствую (буду чувствовать), то пойду к врачу.**

Такое предложение имеет значение потенциального условия.

Answer (score 0):

Формально правильно, но звучит странно. Речь идет о настоящем времени. Смысл таков: говорящий не утверждает и не опровергает того, что он плохо себя чувствует в данный момент, но если это факт, что он плохо себя чувствует сейчас, то он (вскоре) пойдет к врачу.

Вероятно, вы хотели сказать: "Если я плохо себя чувствую, то (я) иду к врачу".
Смысл здесь иной: всякий раз, когда я себя плохо чувствую, я иду к врачу.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае имеет место одна из двух проблем:

1. либо задан не тот вопрос в заголовке. Я хочу сказать, что тема *"Условное предложение в русском языке"* — не совсем соответствует ошибке в предложении *"Если я плохо себя чувствую, то я пойду к врачу"*;
2. либо в описании приведен не самый подходящий пример

Русский язык позволяет сообщить: *"Если идёт дождь, то мы останемся дома"*. Вполне приемлемое предложение.

Что касается приведенного вами примера, то он правилен с точки зрения грамматики, но **совершенно непонятно о чём идёт речь в предложении**, понятно одно: говорящий и сам не знает: плохо ли ему в настоящий момент, или хорошо; болеет ли он, или здоров.